# Simple utility to see HTTP and HTTPS requests and responses for ALL network

Tags: api, http, https

I know Fiddler and Wireshark. But they are both hard to work with, specially wireshark.

I wonder, is there a simpler tool to see the HTTP and HTTPS request/responses for the entire network?

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do that makes them hard? What details do you want?

Comment: Configuring Wireshark on Ubuntu to capture HTTPS traffic is tricky, and for me most of the time it does not work. The `SSLKEYLOGFILE` file does not contain the capture keys. It does not work with Google Chrome, and it fails with Firefox too.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati HTTPS is a secured protocol, that is the reason why accessing it's plain text data it is not simple. There are network level interception proxies e.g. for companies available which work similar to fiddler but on all the traffic. Unfortunately they are not cheap and AFAIK sold as in hardware not as pure software.

Comment: What you're asking is not simple at all, specially if you want to capture HTTPS. Better to stick with what you already have.